# ¿Cómo agregar elemento a un ArrayList de tipo Clase en Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, clase

Tengo un ArrayList de tipo Clase creada por mi con un metodo .add y quiero agregarle elementos desde el main.

Se como agregar elementos a un ArrayList de tipo String por ej y agregarle elementos desde el main pero no se como se hace cuando el Array es de tipo Clase creada por mi.

Comment: Un `String` es una clase como cualquiera que puedas crear tu, así que el modo de hacerlo es igual. Por otra parte, intenta siempre agregar el código de lo que has intentado para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenida @Sofi a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Solamente indicas al declarar el `ArrayList` que el mismo va a guardar dentro objetos de `MiClase`, haciendo esto: **`ArrayList<MiClase>`**. Luego, al agregar los elementos con `add`, tienes que pasarle instancias de objetos de `MiClase`.

Es lo mismo que haces con `String` o con cualquier otro tipo de objeto.

Luego en la lectura, puedes usar cualquier método de `MiClase`, como muestra el ejemplo llamando a `getDataOne()`.

---

#### Código <kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/PUNDI82025)</kbd>

```
    ArrayList<MiClase> mList = new ArrayList<MiClase>();
    //ArrayList<MiClase> mList = new ArrayList<>(); /*Versiones modernas de Java*/

    /*Agregando creando directamente instancias de MiClase*/
    mList.add( new MiClase("Dato1",1) );
    mList.add( new MiClase("Dato2",2) );

    /*Creando primero la instancia y agregándola luego*/
    MiClase mcThree=new MiClase("Dato3",3);
    mList.add(mcThree);
    
    /*Prueba*/
    for(MiClase mc : mList) {
        System.out.println(mc.getDataOne());
    }
```

**Salida:**

```
Dato1
Dato2
Dato3
```

---